# Render dynamic raw XML data on loading a route

Tags: azure, vue.js, seo, sitemap, azure-static-web-app

I am currently working on generating dynamic sitemaps for my website. The site is build on Vuejs and its deployed on Azure static web app. I want to optimize my SEO for google.

The current stage of the project is that I am able to generate sitemaps and store them in storage account. All sitemaps are linked to sitemap index file which is stored in the public folder of Vuejs and that is then available on root when its deployed through git.

The problem is that a single sitemap file can store only 50k URLs so if it exceed we need to create a new sitemap and then add the link of that new file in the sitemap index file. But this wont be possible since right now our sitemap index file is static as in it cant be changed once deployed to static web app. Therefore, I want to make this file dynamically changable.

**My workarounds:**

- I added the link of my storage in sitemap_index.xml route so when
  google loads this route it will be redirected the storage path where
  the sitemap index file is.

**Vue Routes file:**

```
{
   path: '/sitemap_index.xml',
   beforeEnter() { location.href = 'https://example.blob.core.windows.net/$web/sitemap_index.xml' }
},
```

And in order for this route to be acessible I added them in staticwebapp.config.json file as well since this is used for rewrites.

**staticwebapp.config.json file:**

```
 {
 "routes": [
    {
        "route": "/robot.txt",
        "rewrite": "/robot.txt"
    },
    {
        "route": "/sitemap_index.xml",
        "rewrite": "/sitemap_index.xml",
        "headers": {
            "content-type": "text/xml"
        }
    },
    {
        "route": "/sitemap.xml",
        "rewrite": "/sitemap.xml",
        "headers": {
            "content-type": "text/xml"
        }
    }
 ],
 "navigationFallback": {
    "rewrite": "index.html"
 },
 "mimeTypes": {
    ".json": "text/json"
 }
}
```

Now its seems fine but when I upload the sitemap_index.xml path on google, I get an error of HTML found. Apparently the vue app loads first and then redirects to xml file. Hence google first gets the response in html which is invalid.

- Second, I tried pointing the sitemap index to the other sitemap index on storage. This didnt threw any errors but didn't discover any URLs so I figure this will not work either.

I am out of options. I need to know how to edit files in static web app or a way to make xml files dynamically accessible on viewing a route E.g sitemap_index.xml. Thanks in advance.

Comment: How are you expecting sitemaps to help your SEO?  Most sites won't benefit from sitemap files.  Sitemap files don't help rankings and they rarely get Google to index pages that wouldn't otherwise be indexed.   At best sitemaps can tell Google about preferred URLs and give you extra stats in Google Search Console.  See [The Sitemap Paradox](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/4803/the-sitemap-paradox)